# How can I put two div elements on one row?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put the following two `<div>` elements on the same row. How should I do this?

```
<nav>
  <div class="logo" style="background:#00f; margin-right:100px; margin-left:1150px;">
    <img src="jiasaz-4.png" width="100px" height="100px">
  </div>

  <div class="menu" style="background:#f00;">
    <img src="jiasaz-4.png" width="100px" height="100px">
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Use `display: inline-block;` in the CSS.

Comment: Through a plethora of different methods, like `float` and `display: inline-block`. What have you already tried?

Comment: Remove the margins to start with!!

Comment: Placed classes in code sample

Comment: reduced code to just the parts in question, reduced spacing to better wrap (though it's still slightly too wide).

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, Use this css

```
.logo, .menu{ display:inline-block'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use table for that. If you don't want to use table then use `CSS float` property.

```
float : left;
position: Relative;
display:inline;
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to keep it short ;). There are multiple ways of doing that. Main part is trying to keep it simple and understand each step you take. Then step by step everything (CSS & HTML) makes sense.

```css
.logo { 
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}
.logo img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 80px;   
}

/* just to color up things */
header { background-color: tomato }
.logo { background-color: firebrick }
.menu { background-color: wheat }
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
      <img src="http://www.jiasaz.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/jiasaz-4.png">
  </div>
  <nav class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Just a one suggestion. Separate CSS from HTML. This will make it a lot easier to read and maintain when project becomes bigger - trust me ;).

Take look on HTML:
We have two elements - logo and menu which are wrapped by header.

> The **header** element represents a container for introductory content
>   or a set of navigational links.

.. maybe this is too long .. I'll create another post

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.logo{ float: left;
       display: inline;
       width: 25%;}

.menu{ float: left;
       display: inline;
       width: 60%;}
/* you can use the 15% remaining for padding in menu and logo class*/
nav{
    padding: ;/* try different value */
    }
```